# Foreach getting value null, why?

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am trying to get access to some data in PHP.  If I print my docuements as a JSON object I get the document like so:

```
print_r($url);

[
    {
        "channel": "hello.com",
        "partone": {
            "click": 30580,
            "load": 2156552
        },
        "parttwo": {
            "click": 3274,
            "load": 402327
        },
        "partthree": {
            "click": 406467,
            "load": 903869
        }
    }
]
```

So my main idea is to get the "click" of "parttwo" but I am getting `null`. This is my PHP code where I am making the mistake:

```
foreach ($url[0]['parttwo'] as $obj) {           
            $doc = array();
            $doc['click'] = $obj['click'];

            $param []= $doc;
        }
```

Comment: You are overwriting the decoded string by this: $doc = array();

Comment: Have you decoded the JSON?

Comment: Why not do this instead of a foreach?:  $param[] = $url[0]['parttwo']['click']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fo that data, simply:

```
$array = json_decode($url, true);
$param = $array[0]['part2']['click'];
```

If you really need to loop then:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    $param[] = $value['part2']['click'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer :)